# how to use onclick jQuery event for class

Tags: php, jquery, cookies

How to write oncick event in jQuery for button click and the value should store in cookies in php.

I am new to session and cookies.

EX: Link A
    Link B

If Link A clicked corresponding A form should appears.
  If Link B clicked corresponding B form should appears.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="templates/tmpl_Social/js/jquery.js"></script>
<script>
 $(document).ready(function() {
     $("social_conn1").click(function() {});
 });
</script>
<div class="social_conn1">
    <a rel="nofollow" href="modules/?r=deanos_facebook_connect/login_form"><img border="0" src="">TEACHER SIGNUP</a>
</div>
<div class="social_conn1" style="text-align: center; margin-top: 8px;">
    <a rel="nofollow" href="modules/?r=deanos_facebook_connect/login_form"><img border="0" src="">STUDENT SIGNUP</a>
</div>
```

From the above two links, one for teacher sign up form and another for student signup form, both have different fields. I need if user click teacher sign up means teacher form will open,if student means student form will appears. I need to differentiate weather they sign up by teacher or student. for that how to use cookies in php.

Comment: <script type="text/javascript" src="templates/tmpl_Social/js/jquery.js"></script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("social_conn1").click(function(){
  });
});
</script>


    <div class="social_conn1"><a rel="nofollow" href="modules/?r=deanos_facebook_connect/login_form"><img border="0" src="">TEACHER SIGNUP</a></div>
    <div class="social_conn1" style="text-align: center; margin-top: 8px;"><a rel ="nofollow" href="modules/?r=deanos_facebook_connect/login_form"><img border="0" src="">STUDENT SIGNUP</a></div>

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please don't post code or other essential details in comments - I've added it to your question this time, but in future please click "edit" (just under the "jquery" tag on your question) and add the details directly to your question. You say "the value should store" - _what_ value? What are the A and B forms you mention?

Comment: From the above two links, one for teacher sign up form and another for student signup form, both have different fields. I need if user click teacher sign up means teacher form will open,if student means student form will appears. I need to differentiate weather they sign up by teacher or student. for that how to use cookies in php

Comment: If you're asking for an explanation about how to use cookies and how to make forms appear and disappear, why did you accept the answer below that only covers how to use jQuery to select elements by class? That answer certainly points out the problem with the class selector, but it doesn't cover what you asked about.

Comment: ya the below answers works fine, I had another queries as, how to set  cookies for onclick values, and how to get cookies values used as condition in another php file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing the "."

```
$(".social_conn1").click(function() {});
```

Comment: Thank for your update, it's working fine. I had another couple of queries, how to set cookies for onclick values, and how to get cookies values